# Are Tomcat 7 based Spring applications immediately portable to JBoss EAP6?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, jboss-eap-6

OpenShift offers the possibility to develop Spring based applications using JBoss EAP6. I am considering migrating a Spring application developed/deployed on Tomcat 7.

I have little experience with JBoss. Am I going to go through many troubles if I migrate my application? If yes which? Are Tomcat 7 and JBoss EAP6 compatible?

Comment: Just do it and identify and fix any issues individually, each for which you can ask a concrete question here.

Comment: I would if I had a lot of spare resources, but I don't right now. I was wondering whether someone had experience with this. It would help me estimated the risk/benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general response will be yes, JBoss will provide all the standard elments Tomcat does.  But it is always possible to make it not compatible (using directly some tomcat class, JBoss Web use a different name space and there is no 1:1 corespondances).

I most cases you will need to make some litle addaptation (add some configuraiton and properties, change datasource name...).

[JBoss AS7 documentation contains some Spring integration elements](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide).

Some elments provided by default in JBoss may give you some trouble (like JPA), but if you have full controle on the application source, you should be able to get it working without lot of efforts.

Without inside on your application it will be difficult to give concreate effort estimate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on your application.

The servlet container in JBoss 6 is based on Tomcat 6. If you are using any new features in Tomcat 7 (e.g. extensions in the Servlet 3.0 or JSP 2.2 spec), these will not run on JBoss 6.

Comment: Jboss EAP6 = Jboss.org 7, and Jboss.org 6 already support Servlet 3.0 and JSP 2.2 (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS)